# Insert CSS from Chrome Storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I just started creating an extension for Chrome.
I've managed to create an option page where you can type in css-code and when clicking on the save button it's stored in the variable "custom-css" via chrome.storage.sync.set

I can retrieve with chrome.storage.sync.get but don't understand how I can inject this custom code to all pages, for example change all links to a different color.

manifest.json

```
   {
  "name": "Test Extension",
  "description": "Simple Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
     "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": false,
      "js": [ "/js/content.js"],
      "matches": [ "\u003Call_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
   } ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
  "host_permissions": [ "http://*/", "https://*/" ],
  "icons": {
      "16": "/images/icon_16.png",
      "32": "/images/icon_32.png",
      "48": "/images/icon_48.png",
      "128": "/images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "options_page": "/html/options.html"
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tabId },
      files: ["/js/inject.js"]
    })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("INJECTED CSS.");
        })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
```

inject.js

```
//Get Custom CSS Variable and inject
chrome.storage.sync.get({'CustomCSS' : ""}, function (result) {
    CustomCSS = result.CustomCSS;
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, { code: CustomCSS });
});
```

The error I get in the console is: Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertCSS' of undefined

Comment: Remove inject.js and use chrome.scripting.insertCSS instead of executeScript.

Comment: got handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.insertCSS(scripting.CSSInjection injection, optional function callback): No matching signature.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't read the documentation for insertCSS.

Comment: yeah noticed it doesn't support code just file. could you instead of saving to chrome storage save to a css-file?

Comment: Read further and you'll see it supports `css`.

Comment: Ah thanks, css: CustomCSS works!